# Is it possible to have both axes linear in bar char?

Tags: echarts

I want to create a histogram with ECharts. I am atempting to do that with the bar chart. My data is structure with an id of its order and a value (Frequency and Amplitude). I got to display the data, but when I want to have the X-axis of logarithmic type i get nothing to display. I am just intersted if this is at all possible to achieve.

This is the bit of the options:

```
xAxis: {
    type: this.props.options.XaxisMode.value
},
yAxis: {
  type: this.props.options.YaxisMode.value
},
dataset: {
  source: this.data
},
series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    dimensions: [{name: 'Frequency', type: 'int'},{name: 'Amplitude', type: 'number'}],
    large: true
}],
```

this.data is structured as an array of items like ([id,value])

And the axisMode variables can be set to all different 4 types.

Just to elaborate a bit more, [this](https://dadorran.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/plotting_frequency_spectrum_demo_101.png) is what I need to do.

Comment: Can you post your ECharts options code so I can reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I tried, there is no issue displaying `log` type axis with a `value` axis. As long as your `dimensions` in your `series` array give the correct types for your data, there shouldn't be any issue. If you need to change the log base, add `logBase` to your `xAxis` (default is 10).

Also it would look nicer with a line chart like in your screenshot example:
[image: Log chart with line series]
...than the bar type in your code sample:
[image: Log chart with bar series]

Here is the test code I used, based on yours:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'log',
    logBase: 10
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  dataset: {
    source: [
      [1, 0.56],
      [2, 0.15],
      [3, 0.24],
      [4, 0.75],
      [5, 0.86],
      [6, 0.21],
      [7, 0.50],
      [8, 0.11],
      [9, 0.85],
      [10, 0.14],
      [20, 0.50],
      [25, 0.15],
      [50, 1.25],
      [80, 0.51],
      [90, 0.15],
      [100, 0.25]
    ]
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    dimensions: [{
      name: 'Frequency', 
      type: 'int'
    },{
      name: 'Amplitude',
      type: 'number'
    }],
    large: true,
  }],
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.